# Adding Up All Values In A File

Tags: logging

I have a massive 313,000 Line log that looks like below. I'm trying to find a quick way to add up all the Player Online: (number)/100 . So just basically add all the (Number) together.

Example Of Data:

```
[04-28-2018 22:49:30] TPS: 20.0 Memory free: 2394.0/4551.0 (52%) Players online: 19/100 Total chunks loaded: 8413 Total entities: 1532
```

java logging

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for awk!  Assuming the format is somewhat stable the following awk script should do the job:

```
$ cat t1
[04-28-2018 22:49:30] TPS: 20.0 Memory free: 2394.0/4551.0 (52%) Players online: 20/100 Total chunks loaded: 8413 Total entities: 1532
[04-28-2018 22:49:30] TPS: 20.0 Memory free: 2394.0/4551.0 (52%) Players online: 20/100 Total chunks loaded: 8413 Total entities: 1532
[04-28-2018 22:49:30] TPS: 20.0 Memory free: 2394.0/4551.0 (52%) Players online: 20/100 Total chunks loaded: 8413 Total entities: 1532
[04-28-2018 22:49:30] TPS: 20.0 Memory free: 2394.0/4551.0 (52%) Players online: 20/100 Total chunks loaded: 8413 Total entities: 1532
[04-28-2018 22:49:30] TPS: 20.0 Memory free: 2394.0/4551.0 (52%) Players online: 20/100 Total chunks loaded: 8413 Total entities: 1532

$ awk '{po=$11; split(po,a,"/"); sum+=a[1]} END {print sum}' t1
100
```

Basically the steps are:

1) Assign position 11 of each line to the variable po
2) Split po on the / character and assign the pieces to the array a
3) Add the first element of array a to the running sum variable
4) END matches after all the data has been read, print the running sum total

If there's other data in the file, you can tell awk to just process lines that match a specific pattern, e.g:

```
$ awk '/TPS:/ {po=$11; split(po,a,"/"); sum+=a[1]} END {print sum}' t1
```

Awk is installed by default on Mac and Linux, and can be downloaded for free on Windows.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21927944/988525 or a quick google search.  Cygwin or the new Windows Linux Subsystem are a bit more work to setup, but will open up a world of wonderful tools that can be used for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time question, and doesn't have to be scripted, you could also load the file into your favorite spreadsheet program and use text-to-columns to split the data.  The goal being to end up with the players online in a single column that can be summed of course. More manual, but if the data is messy and it's a one-time thing this can be a helpful approach to cleaning it up for analysis.